# How to send emails with google sheets using a template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to run the script below sending emails from the template in Sheet[1] A1.
Each time the script triggers it selects the data for fillInTheTemplate function from the range

I require the email to be sent only from rows which do not have EMAIL_SENT in column 36

```
 * Sends emails from spreadsheet rows.
 */
function sendEmails() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dsh = ss.getSheets()[0];//repl with getshbyname
  const drg = dsh.getRange(2, 1, dsh.getLastRow() - 2, 36);
  const vs = drg.getValues();
  const tsh = ss.getSheets()[1];//repl with getshbyname
  const tmpl = tsh.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const grg = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 6, 36);
  objects = getRowsData(sheet, grg);
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
  var rowData = objects[i];}
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let emailSent = r[35]; 
    let status = r[10];  
    if (status == 'PRICE ONLY' && emailSent != 'EMAIL_SENT') { 
    MailApp.sendEmail(r[9], 'SUPER QUOTATION',fillInTemplateFromObject(tmpl, rowData) );//if last paramenter is the options object then you are missing the  null for the body. but since fillInTemplateFromObject is undefined I can not know that
    dsh.getRange(2 + i, 36).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
    }
  });
}

``
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `However the script is unable to pickup the data from the template. I believe the is a issue with the options object.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Your going to have to share your spreadsheet with data so that we can reproduce the problem.  Not all problems are visually apparent without the ability to test with real date were just as much in the dark as you are.

Comment: Are you getting any errors while executing the script? Would you mind sharing them as well? Moreover, how does your spreadsheet look like?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I changed the code from my initial post. The issue I have with the code is that when the email gets sent the fillinTemplateFunction  is selecting the data from the "range const grg = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 6, 36);" . I require the code to select the row which no email has been sent, i.e Column 36 is blank. Please view the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NWeGWi996smYTNnUyb1xP4bzDdDcWhpSvAHn0L9yjaM/edit?usp=sharing. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your script, it seems that your script sends the email by checking the column "K" (column number is  11) and the column of "AJ" (column number is 36) with `if (status == 'PRICE ONLY' && emailSent != 'EMAIL_SENT') {}`. And, when I saw your sample Spreadsheet, the row number which has no value of "EMAIL_SENT" at the columns "AJ" is 5. But, when I saw the column "K", no value is existing. By this, the `status == 'PRICE ONLY' && emailSent != 'EMAIL_SENT'` returns `false`. By this, the email is not sent. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.

If you want to send the email when the column "AJ" has no value of "EMAIL_SENT", how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (status == 'PRICE ONLY' && emailSent != 'EMAIL_SENT') {
```

#### To:

```
if (emailSent != 'EMAIL_SENT') {
```

### Added:

From the following replying,

> The code is sending the email as I require and 'Email_Sent' is placed in column AJ as it should. The problem I have relates with the function fillInTemplateFromObject(tmpl, grg) function. The range I am using for this function is 'const grg = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 5, 36); ' This starts at row 2 rows and includes 5 rows. When I send the email The cell data in the range for the template data is from row 6 even though the row which the Email_Sent is row 4. The Template should take data from the same cells which the Email is being sent.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
  var rowData = objects[i];}
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let emailSent = r[35]; 
    let status = r[10];  
    if (status == 'PRICE ONLY' && emailSent != 'EMAIL_SENT') { 
    MailApp.sendEmail(r[9], 'SUPERMIX QUOTATION',fillInTemplateFromObject(tmpl, rowData) );//if last paramenter is the options object then you are missing the  null for the body. but since fillInTemplateFromObject is undefined I can not know that
    dsh.getRange(2 + i, 36).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
    }
  });
```

#### To:

```
vs.forEach((r, i) => {
  let emailSent = r[35];
  if (emailSent != 'EMAIL_SENT') {
    MailAppaa.sendEmail(r[9], 'SUPERMIX QUOTATION', fillInTemplateFromObject(tmpl, objects[i]));
    dsh.getRange(2 + i, 36).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
  }
});
```

Comment: Apologies, I'll try to be clearer in explaining the issue. The code is sending the email as I require and 'Email_Sent' is placed in column AJ as it should.  The problem I have relates with the function fillInTemplateFromObject(tmpl, grg) function. The range I am using for this function is  'const grg = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 5, 36); ' This starts at row 2 rows and includes 5 rows. When I send the email The cell data in the range for the template data is from row 6 even though the row which the Email_Sent is row 4. The Template should take data from the same cells which the Email is being sent.

Comment: I do not know how to tell the fillInTemplatefromObject function to select the cells from the same row which the email is sent. I hope you will understand what I'm looking to achieve. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @Les Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, I added one more modification point in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question again, I apologize again.

Comment: Yes excellent, this works perfectly. Thanks very much Tanaike